# Why can't I sort a map by values using a function?

Tags: c++, dictionary

I'm trying to sort a map by value. I did a research about how to do it and ended up with the following code. However, it will not compile and I am not sure why.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

bool cmp(pair<int,int> const & a, pair<int,int> const & b)
{
    return a.second != b.second?  a.second < b.second : a.first < b.first;
}

int main()
{
map<int,int>myMap;
for(int i=0,j=10;i<10;i++,j--)
{
    myMap.emplace(i,j);
}
for(map<int,int>::iterator it=myMap.begin();it!=myMap.end();it++)
{
    cout <<  it->first << " " << it->second << endl;
}

sort(myMap.begin(),myMap.end(),cmp);

for(map<int,int>::iterator it=myMap.begin();it!=myMap.end();it++)
{
    cout <<  it->first << " " << it->second << endl;
}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please share the compilation errors with us.

Comment: It is quite long but ok. Let me add it.  edit: It asks me to add some details because my post is mostly code. That doesn't make sense. @RichardCritten

Comment: `std::map` is always sorted by keys. You need to convert to list of pairs first then sort list

Comment: @myaut Even if I use `unordered_map` ,which isn't sorted at all,  I still get an error.

Comment: `std::unordered_map` means that order is unspecified, while `std::sort` requires that elements are ordered by indexes (see my answer)

Answer (score 1):

`std::map` is always sorted by keys. You need to convert to list of pairs first then sort list. Speaking of which, `std::sort` requires random iterators according to its prototype:

```
template< class RandomIt >
void sort( RandomIt first, RandomIt last );
```

Random iterators mean that `std::sort` should be able to access element at any index (i.e. for swapping elements 1 and 3). However, index access doesn't have any sense for map because it is accessed by keys, not indexes.

Example:

```
std::list<std::map<int,int>::value_type> list;
std::copy(myMap.begin(), myMap.end(), std::back_inserter(list));
list.sort(cmp);
```

Comment: I see. In this case `map<int,int>::iterator` is bidirectional. Hence the error.

Comment: It doesn't need to be a `std::list`. It can also be a `std::vector`, in which case `std::find` would be used.

Answer (score 1):

The another (technical) possible cause of errors (aside from that it is nonsense semantically and that map iterators are not random, as @myaut said) is `map` (and `unordered_map`) underlying value type. In your case it is actually `std::pair<const int, int>`. So:

- Your comparison function will not accept it (it will try to bind reference to wrong type)
- Even if you fix it, `sort` will try to move values around, assigning them. And you cannot assign to the `const` variable